# OpenVPN with Wifi Leaks on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-18.04

I have been setting up VPNs on several machines and checking the success of the setup using the following service:

ipleak.net

It appears that a successful setup (on a MacOS, using Tunnelblick) returns the following

[image]

On an Ubuntu machine, I have the following setup using the built-in VPN (and OpenVPN)

[image]

That is, the machine is connected to a Wifi network through which it connects to the Internet. It is also connected to a VPN with the same provider as the that of the Mac above. Note, that the provider is the same, but the actual VPN servers are different.

However, upon checking for leakage, I see this.

[image]

As you can see, there are two different countries at play here. Why is that? Does that mean the VPN is leaking? What can be done to address this issue?

P.S. If it helps, the Ubuntu version was setup using the GUI features and NOT something like `sudo openvpn <vpn.opnv>`

Comment: Why didn't you use the .ovpn file provided by the VPN provider?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why do you think I didnt?

Comment: I think you didn't use it because you said you didn't use it: "P.S. If it helps, the Ubuntu version was setup using the GUI features and NOT something like `sudo openvpn <vpn.opnv>`"

Comment: @MichaelHampton, right. That is correct. However, the GUI version still allowed me to input the `.openv` file at a point. What I meant to say was that I didn't setup and launch this via the command line.

Comment: OK, that makes a bit more sense. I found it confusing the way it was initially worded.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the VPN uses IPv4 only, so IPv6 requests reach the server directly. A web server can use this to determine your IPv6 address even if the server reached via IPv4.

Since you probably don't use IPv6 for anything anyway, your best bet is to simply disable it. Add these two lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

and run `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf` to apply the changes.

Comment: Warning: This disables IPv6, which is rarely desirable. It is better to fix or replace the leaking VPN. It is inexcusable for a VPN to not offer IPv6 service.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, that was my hunch. How can I go about fixing it?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The only reliable fix is that the VPN provider must offer global IPv6 connectivity. If your chosen provider does not, go elsewhere. If they only offer it on some servers, use one of those servers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thank you. I believe the latter to be the case. Is there a way to check it by inspecting the files? Or should I be asking the tech support?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The .ovpn file won't say whether IPv6 (or even IPv4!) is provided. The server configuration will. So you'll have to ask the provider.